# Man-hour vs. person-hour? Is the former now considered politically incorrect?

Tags: gender-neutral, political-correctness

It’s now (often) considered politically incorrect to say *chairman*. We must now say *chairperson* or simply *chair*.

Does the same apply to *man-hour*? Should I instead say *person-hour*? (On say a job application.)

Context examples:

- "Increased US airport security measures since 2011 have wasted an additional 3 (or whatever) billion man-years of standing in queues."
- "This website's interface requires an additional unnecessary mouse-click, thereby costing users 1 million man-hours a year."
- "3 man-hours have been lost due to drivers having to manoeuvre around this fallen tree branch."
- "[The Mythical Man-Month](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mythical_Man-Month)"

I’m not talking about time wasted per person, but rather the grand total of time across all involved persons.

Comment: I think it's well worth reading Douglas Hofstadter's [_A Person Paper on Purity in Language_](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs655/readings/purity.html) which deals with questions like this.

Comment: Interesting, calling someone 'a chair' is highly insulting in many languages...

Comment: Man-hour like horsepower is gender neutral.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18907/discussion-on-question-by-kenny-lj-man-hour-vs-person-hour-is-the-former-now-c).

Comment: This is now a different question. You should post a new question with a title that reflects its contents more accurately, as it seems clear to me (if not to everyone else) that your problem still hasn't been solved. Your question title asks one thing, but the content another. It's hardly fair on the users who have spent time doing research and writing answers.

Comment: My question is still the same: "Is it now politically incorrect to say man-hours rather than person-hours?" My edit was just to elaborate, in response to numerous queries about the context in which I'm using this.

Comment: @Danubian Sailor It may be insulting to call someone a chair but if chairperson is translated by the word chair which is an insult, that would be a translation mistake in whatever language you are referring to.

Comment: The man in all of those words is asexual. This is just idiots finding yet another way to demonstrate their ignorance. 

When Tolkien (for example) said something like "the world of man/men" 

He wasn't saying that it was a sausage party, nor was he saying that it was a patriarchy he was using the word man to mean humankind. 

i.e. the world of men, women, boys and girls. The world of humans.

Answer (score 98):

Political correctness is in the ear of the beholder.

Personally, until I am deemed to be of the huperson race, I will continue to use man hour, manpower, mankind, etc.

And, to answer your question, don't use "person-hour" on a job-application.  It sounds ridiculous (in my opinion).  If you want to use something gender-neutral, you can measure in terms of FTE (Full Time Equivalent).

Comment: Whoa, whoa, whoa, why's she gotta be a wo*man*?

Comment: Agreed (+1).  I take the stance if you intend it to be demeaning, then it is, but if you are speaking using standard vocabulary, then you are communicating. Making up new words to appease a few only serves to confuse the majority and detract from the point at hand.

Comment: Of course, except that that's essentially an opinion, not a canonical answer.

Comment: I agree, Kris.  Although I'm not sure there is a canonical answer to this question.

Comment: I think the `E` in `FTE` actually stands for Equivalent: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-time_equivalent

Comment: @ObsidianPhoenix Thanks.  I don't care to admit how long I've been getting that wrong!

Comment: But when you're a member of the huperson race, male hupeople will be referred to as "people" and female hupeople as "wopeople".  And then everybody will realise that "person" is a sexist term, too, and another round of political correctness will begin.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: ITYM peroffspring. I rather think that when we're members of the huperoffspring race, male huperoffsprings will be referred to as "male huperoffsprings", and female huperoffsprings will be referred to as "female huperoffsprings", on the rare occasions it matters to distinguish. The inspiration for political correctness is not to find "non-sexist" terms to change the labels used to discriminate: it is to reduce people's inclination to discriminate. Whether it's working is another matter ofc.

Comment: @SteveJessop You're quite right, though the list of words we need to correct is quite dparent'ssiblingting.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question to the standards of this site.

Comment: @DavidRicherby More precisely speaking, I believe the term is _dparent’sfeperoffspringsiblinging_. After all, we rarely find things (please pardon my lack of PC here) _duncling_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you for clarifying that parent'speroffspringsiblingar part of my comment.

Comment: Your suggestion of "huperson" is etymologically unsound. "Human" is from Latin *humanus*, and has nothing to do with men, for which the Latin word was *vir*. Substituting "person" for the "man" in "human" makes about as much sense as replacing "supersonic" with "superchildic"; if you really wanted to go that ridiculous route, you should have suggested "huperchild".

Comment: @MarkDominus - huperchild sounds better.

Comment: @MarkDominus If the Latin etymology of _human_ is relevant, then so is the fact that _man_ in English **also** does not mean ‘man [=male person]’, but ‘man [=human being]’. The sense of ‘male human being’ is secondary in English, just like it is in Latin and hence Romance languages (French _homme_, Spanish _hombre_, etc., mean ‘man’ in both senses). The Old English word for ‘male human being’ is _wer_ (as in _werewolf_, which are for some reason specifically male).

Comment: To the various people who suggest that language remain stuck, almost literally, in the Dark Ages, I would suggest that you limit yourself to the technologies which were also common in the Dark Ages.  Ahem.  The professional standard that language be written in gender-neutral terms dates back about 30 years now.  This isn't some new fad and for businesses which are serious about workplace diversity it isn't an option.

Comment: @MarkDominus, Considering the first syllable of "man-hour" has the same root and has exactly the same amount of relation to males... [that's the joke](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/483/894/463.jpg)

Comment: All of you appealing to word origins are missing the point. The meaning and connotations of words change (much as we sometimes wish they didn't). If you call someone a "nigger" in the U.S. in 2017, they will interpret the word based on its strong cultural association with horrific racism and violence, not its Latin origin meaning simply "black". People do not hear an English sentence and mentally trace its etymology. If you speak as if they did, don't complain about being misunderstood.

Comment: It is impossible to differentiate this response from something you would find in the bowels of 4chan /pol, and discussion literally degenerated to someone posting a meme. Hence, I'm pretty sure the original question is inappropriate -- we want questions with objective answers.

Answer (score 32):

## Yes

As @Ste says, this is subjective.  But in my opinion, **yes, you should use a gender-neutral term for tracking work time**. I suggest "worker hours".

(Edit: for context, I'm a Christian who takes the Bible seriously on everything, including gender roles. I see this mainly as an issue of **kindness**, not advocacy for a view of gender.)

Does every term including "man" need revising? Maybe not. And yes, we can make funny-sounding neutral examples. "Personhole" is one I thought of recently, while passing by a storm drain.

But consider how you'd feel if you were a woman on a team of accountants or architects or programmers, and someone said that your last project had taken 300 "man hours". Whoops, sounds like you didn't contribute.

[Douglas Hofstadter's essay](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs655/readings/purity.html) did a lot to change my own feelings on the subject.

I don't take a blanket approach, but I think it's worth considering context. Nobody thinks that "mankind" means only men, so I think it's fine (though "humanity" may be better). But many people think women aren't doctors, so "man hours" to describe physicians' work may reinforce a wrong perception.

**"Worker hours"** sounds less awkward to me than "person hours" and actually conveys the idea better than "man hours", anyway: we're measuring hours of work, not hours of being a man. Similarly, "access hole" might be better than "manhole".

If you can be more accurate, more inclusive, and it doesn't sound awkward, why not?

Comment: I like "utility hole".

Comment: +1 because, although a contradiction to my own answer, it is also entirely correct.  I just take a different stance.

Comment: Interesting. I would never perceive gender- or sex-specific undertones in _man-hours_ anywhere near as easily as I would in _mankind_. I’m reluctant to use monstrosities like _chairperson_ myself (simply because they’re post-rationalising monstrosities) and have no problem with _chairman_ being gender neutral—just like I have no problem with _nurse_ being gender-neutral—but _mankind_ is a word that I would normally eschew and use _humankind_ instead. Indeed, _mankind_ **does** (also) mean men specifically, which is a disadvantage not shared with _chairman_.

Comment: _"post-rationalising monstrosities"_ - I like it!

Comment: So should we change "manpower" to "personpower"? Or perhaps to "womanpower" in contexts in which the people in question happen to be primarily female? Would that be better?

Comment: @Mehrdad "personpower" sounds awkward. Probably in most cases you can just rephrase: "we are understaffed", etc.

Comment: @NathanLong: Why not just get over it and say "manpower" though? Do you (or do other people) really think people are trying to be sexist when they say something like "manpower"?

Comment: @Mehrdad - Just because people aren't _trying_ to be sexist doesn't mean they're not being sexist. (I am not _trying_ to be annoying, but...)

Comment: *The equivalent of [#] working hours* trips off the tongue easier

Comment: The project took 220 man hours and 80 woman hours.

Answer (score 25):

Here is a Google Ngram chart that tracks the frequency of occurrence of "man hours" (blue line) versus "person hours" (red line) in the Google Books database over the years 1900–2008:

[image]

Several things are evident from this chart. First, the frequency of "man hours" (which includes matches for "man-hours," because the Ngram search algorithm reads the two forms as if they were identical) has dropped sharply since about 1970.

Second, though the frequency of "person hours" (and hence also "person-hours") has grown from practically zero in the late 1960s to a smallish but fairly steady frequency in the 2000s, it certainly has not taken up much of the slack from the decline of "man hours." This circumstance strongly suggests that some unidentified expression is standing in for the latter in many situations where "man hours" was used during its heyday. In my view, the likeliest replacement for *man-hours* in many settings is the unadorned noun *hours*.

Third, "man hours" itself appears to be a creature of the twentieth century. Until 1910, its frequency was essentially zero; but between 1910 and 1950, its popularity skyrocketed. It entered its phase of steady decline around 1970 after peaking during the 1950s.

As for what triggered the decline in "man-hours," I think that disapproval (justified or not) of its being a gender-loaded term almost certainly contributed to the drop-off in usage. But this likelihood does not in itself lend weight to the assertion that "man-hours" versus "person-hours" is a zero-sum situation. In fact, the Google Books data tends to undermine the hypothesis that "person-hours" was the main beneficiary of the decline of "man-hours."

---

But if the frequency of "man hours" dropped off significantly and the frequency of "person hours" rose very modestly, what took up the slack for the decline in the former? One possibility is the bland (and gender-neutral) term "work hours." Here is the Ngram chart for "man hours" (blue line) versus "person hours" (red line) versus "work hours" (green line) for the period 1900–2005:

[image: []

The sharp rise in "work hours" begins in the early 1970s, very close to the time when "man hours" begins its sustained decline. This doesn't prove that the two events are causally related, of course, but it at least shows that the Google Books data are consistent with the hypothesis that allegiance may have shifted from "man hours" to "work hours." The same is not true of (for example) the corresponding Ngram chart for "man hours" (blue line) versus "person hours" (red line) versus "hours of work" (green line):

[image]

In any case, it seems likely that the English-speaking world has not felt compelled to limit its options in this area to "man-hours" and "person-hours." Language choices rarely come down to stark dichotomies of that sort, because language can usually offer multiple plausible alternatives.

Answer (score 11):

All this political correctness is sick. **No, you shouldn't use gender-neutral phrases** in place of phrases which have evolved over hundreds of years. We will go crazy reconsidering each word in its political context. All we need is the **meaning** of the language construction, describing an object of reality.

Comment: I don't think this is an answer to the question.  The OP is enquiring about standards of political correctness and how to conform to them.  If you dislike the entire approach, that may be a perfectly valid **comment** but it is not, by the conventions of StackExchange, an answer.

Comment: @itsbruce I think this is a blanket answer, "Don't use gender-neutral phrases at all," and as such it covers the usage of "person hours" in the question. It is a bit of a rant, though.

Comment: Yes, political correctness is horrible, let's go for the opposite instead. If you believe it's stupid to be offended by this, then you must realize that by that logic, those who are offended by political correctness are at least as stupid?

Comment: I understand your sentiment and have seen examples I considered silly. But "meaning" is more that definition, it's also connotation. "Fat" and "overweight" mean roughly the same thing, but "fat" has a more offensive feel. You probably don't use it as freely, because you want to be kind, even if you personally don't see the difference as important. **Being considerate means considering how someone else feels, not how you think they should feel**. If a woman told you she felt excluded by "man hours", would you say "get over it", or try to be considerate?

Comment: To quote Confucius: "If language is not correct, then what is said is not what is meant; if what is said is not what is meant, then what must be done remains undone; if this remains undone, morals and art will deteriorate; if justice goes astray, the people will stand about in helpless confusion. Hence there must be no arbitrariness in what is said. This matters above everything.". How something is formulated matters a great deal - words shape our perception of the world around us. Demagogues demonstrate repeatedly how much influence words can have on our world.

Comment: _"phrases which have envolved in hundreds of years"_ - Assuming you mean "evolved", then by your own definition language changes over time so therefore we _don't_ have to continue forever using these old terms where there are newer, more inclusive terms available. _"It's getting more and more dangerous"_ - Huh? Dangerous? Um...

Comment: Agreed - overly sensitive members of mankind are creating an issue where there is none. See http://www.dailywritingtips.com/mankind-humankind-and-gender/

Comment: Note that the OP's question is specifically about whether "man-hours" is a politically incorrect term, not whether gender-neutral language is a desirable goal from a social, cultural, philosophical, or political perspective. Note, too, that "man-hours" appears to be barely more than 100 years old (Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary assigns it a first-occurrence date of 1912). Like itsbruce, I don't think the poster's response here attempts to answer the OP's actual question. To the extent that the OP's original question invites such generalized responses, I think it's off-topic.

Comment: (Only) *because it is a blanket statement*, I strongly disagree with this answer. Counterpoint: in Portuguese, "[gipsy](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/cigano)" is in the dictionary as "5. someone who acts cleverly to trick or cheat someone else", and "[do jew things](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/judiarias)" as "prank, mock, mistreat". Using these terms will perpetuate the... demonization of those cultures and, to be fair, borders on xenophobia. Just because we're used to these words and don't notice it, doesn't make it any less so. See "being considerate" above, by @NathanLong.

Answer (score 6):

Another potential replacement phrase might be **Labor Hours**

Answer (score 2):

A considerate approach that doesn't transform your statement into one that sounds patronizing and moronic is to choose a different word that conveys the same meaning. For example, if 8 man-hours is the same as 1 technical head count, then divide your total number of man-hours by 8 and state your criterion in TTHC. Or, if by a man-hour you simply mean 1 hour of uninterrupted labor, then state it in terms of labor hours.

In the end, if you are so uncomfortable with a term that you had to doubt yourself about your use of it, then that term is inappropriate for you. Have the cojones (or the you-go-girl attitude) to write what you truly mean and your confidence will be heard; choose equivocating and ingratiating words and your spinelessness will be heard.

Answer (score 2):

In response to the OP's edit which clarifies the context in which the term *man-hour* was perceived to be (possibly) politically  incorrect, I would argue that the term is inappropriate and misleading for the particular situation he describes.

<sup>The OP: *Increased US airport security measures since 2011 have wasted an additional **3** (or whatever) **billion man-[hours] of standing** in queues*</sup>

A more accurate and precise way of saying the time endured (or wasted) by travellers in queues and lines  would be **wait time** or **passenger wait time**.

> [Customs Waits at Airports Found to Be Three to Five Hours](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2013-09-18/customs-waits-at-airports-found-to-be-three-to-five-hours.html)
>
> U.S. Customs and Border Protection staffing shortages are leaving
> arriving international travelers standing in line for nearly five
> hours at the busiest airports, according to a travel industry report.
>
> Peak **wait times** reached a high of 4.5 hours at New York’s John F.
> Kennedy International Airport in December 2012. At Miami in April
> 2013, the peak **wait times** were 4.7 hours.

From The New York Times article *[Why Waiting Is Torture](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/08/19/opinion/sunday/why-waiting-in-line-is-torture.html?pagewanted=all)* (8/18/2012)

> SOME years ago, executives at a Houston airport faced a troubling
> customer-relations issue. Passengers were lodging an inordinate number
> of complaints about the long waits at baggage claim. In response, the
> executives increased the number of baggage handlers working that
> shift. The plan worked: the **average wait** fell to eight minutes, well
> within industry benchmarks. But the complaints persisted. [...]
>
> So the airport decided on a new approach: instead of reducing **wait
> times**, it moved the arrival gates away from the main terminal and
> routed bags to the outermost carousel. Passengers now had to walk six
> times longer to get their bags. Complaints dropped to near zero.

And in another NYT article (4/18/2012)

> [Flying Through Airport Lines](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/04/22/travel/flying-through-airport-lines.html?_r=0)
> MORE than 10 years after the Sept. 11 terrorist attacks completely
> altered the airport experience, travelers have a variety of options
> that will shorten **wait times** at security and immigration.

Comment: Well yes, but I'd like something that can be applied more generally. Not just specifically for wait times. E.g. this website's interface forces each user to make an additional mouseclick, thereby wasting an additional 1 million man-hours per year.

Comment: @KennyLJ 1,000,000 man hours per year is lost in what? Clicking a link? In case it was a typo, or maybe it was deliberate, in your edit you talk about "billion man *years* of standing in queues" Is that hyperbole, or a serious estimate? In any case, I answered your edit: The time spent in waiting in queues is called "wait time" and "passenger wait time" Please see here: http://www.nap.edu/openbook.php?record_id=14589&page=17

Answer (score 0):

You said not to worry about why it's being used... but I can't help it!
Have you ever noticed that getting stuck on a question of weird grammar or social usage is an indicator that you're using the wrong word to begin with?

["Man-Hours"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/man-hour) is not directly derived from the Noun man, rather it refers to [the Verb man.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/man%5B1%5D)

So the important word to consider here is how the word "manning" applies. The Verb man has 2 senses; first "to be at your station", second "to assign to stations". These 2 senses bring up the concept of perspective. If you are the person manning the station you are spending literal hours, if you are management making assignments you are spending man-hours.This harmonizes with standard business usage of man-hours which is either for estimation purposes or for cost accounting.

I looked for a good reference on this. While it's easy to find a ton of references showing that man-hour is primarily used for estimation and cost accounting, it's very hard to validate that it is *only* used that way.

So I'll propose some thought experiments to demonstrate that we have an intuition about correct usage;

"Wow I'm tired. I worked 12 (hours or man-hours) today."

"Staffing is going to take 78 (hours or man-hours) to keep this store open 24 (hours or man-hours) a day."

"That will take 3 hours for the two of us to finish. It's 5pm now, it will be on your desk (at 8pm or 11am tomorrow)."

"That will take 3 man-hours to finish. It's 4pm now, the 3 of us (can or can't) have it done by 5."

"It takes 2 hours from the time the metal is poured until it can be packed for shipping,  at a cost of .12 (hours or man-hours) per part."

So assuming that your instincts have been guided by standard business usage (and not distorted by a [pointy-haired-boss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointy-haired_Boss) who missuses it and every other buzzword), you'll see that you would never refer to *literal hours that you personally spent* as "man-hours".

Using the correct term clarifies the gender aspect by clarifying that the subject is non-gendered in the first place.
If your industry doesn't use the term "manning" don't use "man-hour". (Manning remains a current phrase in manufacturing, since it clarifies the scope of discussion to the time of actual machine operators and excludes support staff and management.)

Using the phrase Labor Hours (as TD pointed out) clarifies the focus of the discussion is the work and NOT the identity of the workers.

In non-manufacturing (or military) contexts you probably are actually talking about:

- "Staff hours" - includes support staff
- "Business hours" - specific to the hours a business defines itself as "open"
- "Project hours" - specific to the fractured nature of time spent on a project by one or
  more persons
- "Billable hours" - profession specific

{ References: You're not going to find precompiled discussions of the origin of "man-hour". 
So if you need to validate the above statements you'll have to do your own Etymology research. 
The following are some samples of highly edited and regulated usage of "man hour" as a measurement of "manning" and "manpower".

US Army - [www.apd.army.mil/pdffiles/r570_4.pdf](http://www.apd.army.mil/pdffiles/r570_4.pdf)

US Navy - [www.public.navy.mil/bupers-npc/organization/navmac/Documents/MANPOWERGLOSSARY.doc](http://www.public.navy.mil/bupers-npc/organization/navmac/Documents/MANPOWERGLOSSARY.doc)

Rand Organization - [www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/monograph_reports/2007/MR1436.p‌​df](http://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/monograph_reports/2007/MR1436.p%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bdf)

These organizations have been using the noun manpower, verb manning, and measurement man-hour since (at least) World War 2. The first attested use of Man Hour is attributed to 1911 in a business context, but the original source is not searchable online.

Comment: You claimed that "man-hours" derive from the verb "to man".  Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Sure I can give you references. But it's not going to be precompiled etymology, you're going to have to do your own reading.
US Army - www.apd.army.mil%2Fpdffiles%2Fr570_4.pdf
US Navy - www.public.navy.mil%2Fbupers-npc%2Forganization%2Fnavmac%2FDocuments%2FMANPOWERGLOSSARY.doc
Rand Organization - www.rand.org%2Fcontent%2Fdam%2Frand%2Fpubs%2Fmonograph_reports%2F2007%2FMR1436.pdf

These organizations have been using the noun manpower, verb manning, and measurement man-hour since (at least) World War 2.

Comment: First of all, the links are all broken, second just because they use "manpower" and the verb "to man" in the same document doesn't prove one was derived from the other.

Comment: Man-hour is a unit name like foot-pound or kilowatt-hour.  It's two quantities that are multiplied together. The name tells you how to do the math to calculate it, just like miles per gallon or dollars per hour. Man is a noun just like any other unit.